# How to override State class so I could access StatefulWidget instance?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have 2 classes:

```dart
class A extends StatefulWidget {
  A({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<A> createState() => _AState();
}

class _AState extends State<A> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  void func(){}
}
```

And I want to override the `_AState` classes `func()` method. So I do this like this:

```dart
class B extends A{
  final item = 10;

  @override
  State<A> createState() => _BState();
}

class _BState extends _AState{
  @override
  void func() {
    widget.item //can't do this
  }
}
```

I have no problem overriding the `func()` method, but now I also need to access my new variable `item`, that is declared in `B` class. And I know I can't do that because instance `widget` is provided by `State<A>` class.

**So my question is: How to access the variable `item` from `B` class in `_BState`?**

Comment: You can try B().item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Cast the widget to `B` object

```
class _BState extends _AState{
  @override
  void func() {
    // (widget as B).item 
  }
}
```